# Is it standard to compare two nouns?

Tags: comparisons

I have come across a sentence comparing two nouns as follows:

> Mr. Hafner is German and has a buttoned-up manner that is more
> boardroom than barn.

In the sentence, the nouns *boardroom* and *barn* are compared much the same way as two adjectives are. Or, they are treated as quasi-adjectives.

Is this kind of comparison a standard practice and widely accepted in both formal and informal writing?

I appreciate grammatical or any suggestions.

Comment: You could call them quasi-adjectives. 'His manner is more [suited to the] boardroom than [to the] barn.'

Comment: The phrase "all talk and no trousers" is pretty idiomatic.  And "all bark and no bite" more so. Though one could argue over whether 'bark' etc are whotsits acting as thingummybobs, etc.

Comment: Yes, it is common in informal and formal writing.

Comment: I've been trying to find other examples of the 'is more N1 than N2' in the 'is more N1 than it is N2' sense, and not found many. Your example sounds fine if a little informal, but I wouldn't say that N1 and N2 can be chosen at will (and always assuming they're not crazily disparate, like 'tyrannosaurus' and 'inkwell'). Far from it. Check candidates, here if you can't find evidence elsewhere. 'More town than gown' is one example I've found. And 'more home than garden' (one example using scare quotes). But these aren't in common use.

Comment: Your 'quasi-adjective' suggestion for this usage makes sense. In 'a football manager', almost all grammarians agree that 'football' is a noun used attributively _as if it were an adjective_, not _as an adjective_. But 'fun' is conceded to have undergone conversion to an adjective ('a fun time'); 'funnest'  exists. Then, as far as I'm aware, the jury is still out on 'steel' in 'a steel bridge'. After all, adjectives like 'wooden' and 'nuclear', classifiers, don't perform well in the tests for adjectives. Possibly, these predicative usages show the conversion-to-adjective process in progress.

Comment: Returning to your question, more literal expressions like 'It is more fort than castle' can be seen as shortened forms of 'It is more a fort than a castle.' Your example is far more subtle, more complex. ' ... more to be expected in ...'.

Comment: "Mr. Hafner is German and has a buttoned-up manner that is more boardroom-type, than barn-type", or as @KateBunting commented  '...more [suited to the] boardroom than [to the] barn.'  I think this type of usages are common.

Comment: I would have liked to see the comments by @EdwinAshworth, summarized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase 'more NOUN than NOUN' appears to be fairly common in both formal and informal contexts. However, most of these cases seem to be comparing the quantity of both nouns rather than the quality of them.

So if your emphasis is on the 'more NOUN than NOUN' construction, I would say the answer is: yes, this is standard, fairly common, and occurs in both formal and informal contexts.

If your emphasis is on the 'quasi-adjectival' nature of the nouns (as you put it), as contrasted to the more common quantitative nature of the nouns in the 'more NOUN than NOUN' construction, than I would say the answer is: yes, this is standard, but maybe not quite that common, and does occur in both formal and informal contexts.

It also struck me looking at examples that this construction seems to have many clichés (like 'more style than substance', 'more bite than bark', 'more questions than answers') but is also still productive (with new ones cropping up like 'more machismo than menace' which may only ever remain extremely rare or unique).

---

Some invented examples to illustrate the distinction I'm making between the constructions that compare quantity, and the ones that compare quality:

- "His threats *had* **more bark than bite**." -> Here I would expand this to mean 'His threats have *both* bark and bite, but there's more bark in them than bite.' So what's being compared is the amount (i.e. quantity) of bark and bite contained in the threats. This type of construction often has an additional adverb that measures the quantity in some way, e.g. "His threats had *much* more bark than bite." or "His threats had *far* more bark than bite."
- "His threats *were* **more bark than bite**." -> Here I would expand this to mean 'His threats are more like bark than they are like bite; they're kind of a bit like both, and also not really either of them, but if I had to compare them to something, I'd say they were more similar to bark than to bite'. So here, what's being compared is the quality of barks and bites, both of which are metaphorically being equated to threats.

---

Some non-invented examples for good measure.

In the British National Corpus (which is 100 million words of British English from the late 20th century, released as a corpus in 2007, see [here](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/)), there are 617 instances of 'more NOUN than NOUN' (which is a frequency of 5.504 instances per million words) [of these 617 instances, 40 were from the spoken part of the corpus]. I've not carried out a detailed analysis of them, but from a quick glance, it seems most of these are about comparing the quantity of two nouns, rather than the quality of them. The actual number of the construction we're interested in is also a bit smaller than this, because some of the 'more NOUN than NOUN' constructions picked up are not some we're interested in here. Below, I give a few of these instances, just for illustration purposes.

Examples that compare the quantity:

- "Psychology is still a subject in which there are far
  **more questions than answers**." [Written, from a periodical]
- "Going to the theatre, concerts and art galleries remains largely the privilege of the well-off and well-educated, and **of more women than men**, research shows." [Written, from a periodical]
- "The good doctor was very excitable and often acted with **more enthusiasm than wisdom**." [Written, from a fiction book]
- "Such a scheme may do **more good than harm**." [Written, from a non-fiction book]
- "But for the rowers taking part there's **more pain than pleasure** in a contest where only the fittest survive." [Written-to-be-spoken, from a television script]
- "Is this a man of much **more style than substance**?" [Spoken, from a radio phone-in]

Examples that compare the quality:

- "The T-shirts are **more machismo than menace**." [Written, from a periodical]
- "This week's striking display of Labour unity was **more show than substance**." [Written, from a periodical]
- "A home that is much **more diy than designer**" [Written, from a periodical]
- "In reality, he was **more pawn than player**." [Written, from a biography book]
- "It seemed **more mammal than bird**" [Written, from a biography book]
- "The death of the old Daily Herald, the longest surviving Labour daily, founded in 1912 and owned by the Labour party for a period between the wars, was **more agony than trauma**." [Written, from a non-fiction book]

Examples where it's not entirely clear if it's the quantity or quality being compared:

- "This development allowed the area of window relative to wall to increase to a maximum in the 1900s when the façades of mills became **more glass than brick**." [Written, from a non-fiction book]
- "It looked **more silver than gold** on this dull, overcast day." [Written, from a fiction book]
- "What they used to sell a er er at er in the lace market at dinnertime, they used to make a big roly pudding, like that, with jam in it and sauce on it, white sauce, it was **more water than sauce**, you know" [Spoken, from an oral history interview]

Examples caught by a 'more NOUN than NOUN' search that we wouldn't be interested in here:

- "Lemons are **more acid than bananas**." -> instance of mis-tagging ('acid' is an adjective here, not a noun.)
- "Some people need a lot **more treatment than others**." -> instance where 'than' isn't separating the two things being compared ('treatment' and 'others' aren't actually being compared, it's 'some people' and 'others' that are being compared).

Comment: Good answer. It is comprehensive, giving false positives that OP hasn't considered. It lists relevant (and possibly relevant) examples. It also mentions the comparative rarity of the relevant examples, though a fuller treatment would be at doctorate level.

Comment: haha, thanks @EdwinAshworth :-) Yes, this could do with a discussion of the comparative frequencies of both uses in different registers and in different varieties of English... but that would indeed be a whole study in and of itself.

Comment: Then there are the '[link-verb] _less_ Nb than Na' strings.  I'd say 'Mr. Hafner is German and has a buttoned-up manner that is less barn than boardroom' doesn't really work. //  'In reality, he was more pawn than player' seems closely linked to 'In reality, he was more a pawn than a player', while 'A home that is much more diy than designer' obviously uses the nouns as attributive relicts. Perhaps these need separating?

Comment: If your invented example ("His threats had more bark than bite.") is to compare quantity, why don't you use the plural forms? "His threats had more **barks** than **bites**."

Comment: @JK2 - hm that's an interesting question. I don't think that example means there are (several) barks and their number is more numerous than the number of bites. I think it means a greater proportion of the threats is of a bark-nature than of a bite-nature. So perhaps the distinction I'm drawing doesn't stand up very well... or perhaps I've not chosen a good example. There's obviously a difference between "There are more women than men" and "This has more style than substance"... but perhaps to distinguish between the two, it's sufficient to consider whether the NOUNS or plural or not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - yep, I agree with your point as well. Looks like more distinction is needed between the separate cases. I have to admit, I was trying to give as simple an answer as I could, basically to say 'yep, this is not uncommon as attested by examples from a corpus'. But it looks like this really could do with a more detailed study :-)

Comment: @JK2 - I was tempted to go and reclassify my examples. But it still seems to me that there is a distinction between the examples I'm putting under 'quantity' and those I'm putting under 'quality': basically, it's the answer to the question is "Is there both X and Y or neither?"If A has *both* X and Y (but more X than Y), than I call it 'quantity'. If A is *neither* X nor Y, but at a push, more like X than Y, than I call it 'quality'. [For instance, the scheme does both good and harm, but more of the good than of the harm. The animal is neither mammal nor bird. But it looks more like a mammal.]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - about your other point (the less NOUN than NOUN construction), interesting observation, but I'm not sure if it's accurate. In the BNC, there are 58 examples of "less NOUN than NOUN", so that's far less than of the "more NOUN than NOUN" but they still do occur. Of course, not all would be relevant to us here, but just to give one example that would: "television news gave them less coverage than defence" [written, from a book on world affairs]. As to whether, "less" can replace "more" in every instance... that's another interesting question to consider in a more detailed study!

Comment: 'Give' is not a link-verb. The nouns ('coverage', 'defence') are DOs here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - ah my bad I hadn't twigged that you'd included link-verbs inside your construction (that's just me not paying attention). I've not found any examples of "LINK-VERB less NOUN than NOUN" in the BNC (though I'm just having a quick look). The closest I've got is "There was less humour than triumph in the sound" but that's still not the same construction. It's always difficult to prove absence, but certainly a quick glance at the BNC supports your suggestion that, at best, that construction is less frequent than more NOUN than NOUN. It'd be interesting to look at more data...

Answer (score 2):

I know this response is late in the game, but I wanted to narrow the focus to the noun-comparison pattern that includes a linking verb: `[to be] more NOUN than NOUN`.

This pattern is indeed common in writing. It’s also linguistically “productive”—that is, it can be applied to produce practically countless instances of its kind with nouns of the writer’s choice (e.g. *the street is more pothole than pavement*, *his book is more recipe than reflection*, *the river is more sandbar than waterway*—see at end for more samples from the corpus).

With its imprecise measure and sometimes rhetorical whimsy, the construction doesn’t lend itself to use in, say, a science paper. But it’s widely accepted in formal writing, especially in journalism, where stylistic brevity and flair is valued.

It seems to me that these nouns following the linking verb usually function normally—as predicate nouns (e.g. like *president* in *I am president*)—and not like predicate adjectives (e.g. like *presidential* in *I am presidential*). But perhaps your particular example is a little different (we’ll get to that at the end).

.

The `[to be] more NOUN than NOUN` comparison is used to weight two qualities or characteristics within someone or something, like this:

> *By now, the mud puddle is more mud than puddle, and the game of tag morphs into mud wrestling.*
>
> <sub>[Source: The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/lifestyle/2001/08/16/xx-marks-the-spot/0b2e78c7-0661-4975-89ff-c5de471da1aa/)</sub>

We can imagine it expanded out using the preposition *like* (having the characteristics of) in front of the nouns:

> *By now, the mud puddle is more [like] mud than [like a] puddle . . .*

Or we can conceptually understand it sort of like “more parts this and fewer parts that”:

> *By now, the mud puddle is [two parts] mud + [one part] puddle . . .*

Nouns all, I would say. We can turn the nouns into adjectives by appending an adjective-forming suffix such as *-like*:

> *By now, the mud puddle is more mud-like than puddle-like . . .*

.

Depending on the nouns, the imaginary expansion might be better served by the preposition *of*, which combines with *more* to mean *to a greater extent or degree*:

> *There’s no simple list of actions departing CEOs should take; planning the outgoing transition is more art than science.*
>
> <sub>[Source:
> Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/2011/02/09/executive-transition-last-100-days-leadership-managing-mckinsey.html?sh=29030d031631)</sub>
>
> *. . . planning the outgoing transition is more [of an] art than [a] science.*

.

Quite often, these patterns employ rhetorical devices like metaphor, metonymy, and synecdoche. (Noun alliteration is also often involved.) In the first example below, *horse* and *zebra* are nouns used in their usual sense. In the second, those same nouns are used as metaphors for *uncommon* and *ordinary*:

> *[The zorse] was more horse than zebra but still had some features like some stripe patterns and a mane that stuck up, but it was tall
> like a horse.* 
> <sub>[Source:
> Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/oxcsw/why_were_zebras_not_domesticated_like_horses/)</sub>
>
> *In contrast, many clinicians view the disorder as uncommon, more zebra than horse.* 
> <sub>[Source: Endocrine
> Practice](https://www.endocrinepractice.org/article/S1530-891X(20)35593-2/fulltext)
> (login required)</sub>

Here are some more metaphors:

> *The Cubs’ interest is more smoke than fire, one person with knowledge of the situation said. They would prefer to land a younger,
> team-controlled starter.* 
> <sub>[Source: Detroit Free
> Press](https://www.freep.com/story/sports/mlb/tigers/2017/07/08/detroit-tigers-trade-rumors/461903001/)</sub>

*Smoke* and *fire* are used to signal mild vs. blazing interest. (I would further call temperatures *mild* and *blazing* metaphors for *moderate* and *extreme*.)

And more:

> *Reminiscent of the song “Ocean Rain,” the placement of this track at the beginning is a hint that this album is more candlelight than
> glitterball.* 
> <sub>[Source:
> SortMusic](http://www.sortmusic.com/_e/echo-and-the-bunnymen-albums,up643443106627,len.html)</sub>

There, we have both metonymy and metaphor. *Candlelight* and *glitterball* stand in metonymously for something like quiet evening vs. night at the dance club, which in turn metaphorically signal contemplative vs. kinetic ambience.

.

In the metaphors above, the nouns stand in for adjectives (*zebra* = *uncommon*, *fire* = *blazing*, *dance club* = *kinetic*, etc.), but I don’t think that changes their function in the sentence; they’re still syntactically predicate nouns following linking verbs. Similarly: Even though we understand the metaphorical *You’re toast* to mean *You’re finished*, we don’t consider *toast* to function like an adjective there.

.

Still, I can imagine a case for an adjective interpretation. Here’s another noun interpretation, as above:

> *The flavor is more cucumber than melon, with a peppy citrus kick.* 
> <sub>[Source: The National Gardening
> Association](https://garden.org/plants/view/124102/Mexican-Sour-Gherkin-Cucumber-Melothria-scabra/)</sub>
>
> *The flavor is more [like] cucumber than [like] melon . . .*
>
> Append an adjective-forming suffix: *The flavor is more cucumbery than
> melony . . .*

But if we imagine an elliptical noun *flavor*, we could argue that *cucumber* and *melon* are vestigial attributive nouns (which function as adjectives), stripped of their shared noun:

> *The flavor is more [like a] cucumber [flavor] than [like a] melon [flavor] . . .*

Note that the adjective approach doesn’t work with our mud puddle:

> ? *By now, the mud puddle is more [like a] mud [mud puddle] than [like
> a] puddle [mud puddle]* (questionable)

So what’s going on with your sentence (inspired by the interesting New York Times article ([The Business of Burps: Scientists Smell Profit in Cow Emissions](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/05/01/business/cow-methane-climate-change.html))?

> *Mr. Hafner is German and has a buttoned-up manner that is more boardroom than barn.*

Are these functioning as nouns?

> ? *Mr. Hafner has a buttoned-up manner that is more [like a] boardroom
> than [like a] barn.*
>
> ? *Mr. Hafner is more [like a] boardroom than [like a] barn.*

Hm, a manner or a person isn’t at all like a boardroom or a barn, like a room or building. Sure, there are things associated with boardrooms and barns, but there’s a missing link. What I see here is:

> *Mr. Hafner has a buttoned-up manner that is more boardroom [manner] than barn [manner].*
>
> *Mr. Hafner has a buttoned-up manner that is more [like a] boardroom [manner] than [like a] barn [manner].*

As with *flavors* above, if we imagine an elliptical *manner*, we can argue that *boardroom* and *barn* are vestigial attributive nouns functioning like adjectives.

.

To summarize, the `[to be] more NOUN than NOUN` pattern is widely used, productive, and accepted in writing, formal and informal. I can understand arguments for adjective (quasi, attributive, or otherwise) interpretations in these patterns, but my sense is that these nouns mostly don’t jump the fence.

.

Here are some searches from [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/):

When the results appear, click ALL FORMS (SAMPLE): 500 at the top of the second column to see sample usage. From there, if desired, click a numbered row to see expanded context.

[is more _nn1 than _nn1](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=96609678) (simple search—*is* with singular nouns; you’ll need to disregard false positives headed by the dummy *there*—such as *There is more stupidity than hydrogen in the universe, and it has a longer shelf life.* [—attrib. Frank Zappa])

[_vb more _nn1 than _nn1](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=96609746) (all *to be* inflections with singular nouns; again, disregard dummy *there*s.)

[_nn1 is more _nn1 than _nn1](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=96609600) (singular noun with *is* and singular nouns)

Comment: 'with its imprecise measure and sometimes rhetorical whimsy' is more Truman Capote Award than ELU. 'More art than science' and 'more fact than fiction' are the ones I was grasping for, and 'more candlelight than glitterball' is sensational, and a fair argument for the device being highly productive ('is more N1[-related] than N2[-related]'). _And I was about to DV for bandwaggoning_ :(

Comment: Interesting discussion, thanks for sharing! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically speaking, I would say that the comparison isn't between the two nouns, but the similarity of the subject's mannerism (The German Mr. Hafner's buttoned-up manner) to a boardroom as opposed to a barn.

So it's not so much comparing a boardroom to a barn, but it is like comparing a subject's similarity to one adjective (presumably used to describe their personality or characteristic) to another adjective.

Here the nouns are used as substitutes to adjectives because the nouns are meant to be representative of certain characteristics, so they are used as if they are adjective in a way here.

Comment: But OP is asking whether 'X is more N1 than N2' where N1, N2 are nouns qualifying (not quantifying) X is a productive construction. 'His manner is more [suited to the] boardroom than [to the] barn', as @Kate says, is a pretty transparent deletion, and sounds acceptable in informal registers,  but is say 'His behaviour is more monkey than donkey' acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that this construction isn't comparing two nouns. I see it as creating an ad hoc path between the named items, where ordinarily, you wouldn't regard them as being connected.

> ... is more fiction than fact
> ... is part fiction, part fact

At the vary least, the *more X than Y* construction creates a need for some sort of middle from which to base the comparison. The second one does not.

This can work just fine within literal, figurative, metaphorical, or any other circumstances because it is a construction. And there really doesn't seem to be any restrictions on the sort of things that can be used as targets as long as the context lets you connect the dots.

We normally don't consider *fact* and *fiction* to be on a continuum, but we can force it with this construction -

> ... an autobiography that is (regarded by scholars as) more fiction than fact.

(I made this one up)

This construction does more than provide a simple apportionment of X and Y. The path connecting the two can be customized by context. We can place waypoints. In the above example, this is left to one's intuition. In a formal context, you would want to make sure there are waypoints on the path that help identify the middle.

> The next challenge is to establish evidence-based protocols for
> goal-directed fluid therapy so that perioperative fluid management can become more
> science than art.

https://pubs.asahq.org/anesthesiology/article/130/5/677/18876/Perioperative-Fluid-ManagementTurning-Art-to

Comment: Thank you so much for the insightful analysis. The idea of an ad hoc path is revelatory and eye-opening.

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael_Lai suggests, it is not a plain comparison of two nouns, but a comparison of two attitudes (in this case, I guess to work).

Grammatically, I would say the construction looks ill-formed because of the metaphorical use of the terms "boardroom" and "barn". A correspondence between *manner* (tenor of the metaphor) and two vehicles (*boardroom* and *barn*) is traced to describe the nature of his mannerism. It looks more complex because of the comparison, but it could be divided into two:

*Mr. Hafner is German and has a buttoned-up manner that is boardroom.
Mr. Hafner is German and has a buttoned-up manner that is not barn.*

The use of the two vehicles reinforces the meaning, emphasizing the contrast between the two working places. The properties of the boardroom are ascribed to the tenor (his manner), meaning that he's focused on benefits, efficient planning, marketing strategies... On the other hand, the barn represents a rural place where hands are used to work; it is more physical rather than intellectual. Also, a boardroom is usually seen as a clean organized space where you would wear a suit. In a barn, you have to get your hands dirty.

Comment: But OP is asking whether 'X is more N1 than N2' where N1, N2 are nouns qualifying (not quantifying) X is a productive construction. 'His manner is more [suited to the] boardroom than [to the] barn', as @Kate says, is a pretty transparent deletion, and sounds acceptable in informal registers,  but is say 'His behaviour is more monkey than donkey' acceptable?

Comment: Although metaphors rely heavily on individual interpretation and their meaning can vary drastically from one culture to another, I would say it is a productive construction as far as the use of metaphors in formal and informal style is accepted. I consider your suggestion also acceptable; its structure is also transparent since the use of certain animals to create metaphors is well-documented. However, when you are using metaphors you're taking the risk of not being understood, especially if you're not using well-known metaphors that are already part of the common language.

Comment: The question was 'Is it standard ...?'. The answer is 'No.' If the question had been 'Is any rule of grammar broken ...?' the answer might well have been different.  But Orwell's Sixth law ('avoid the quirky / outlandish / ugly except for eg comedic effect') trumps all others.

Answer (score -2):

I think the question is not so much about "comparing two nouns" as about "matching two nouns". Specifically, I think it's about matching two count nouns without any articles.

> Mr. Hafner is German and has a buttoned-up manner that is more **boardroom** than **barn**.

Here, both the matched nouns are count nouns, but you don't need any articles. In fact, it can even get awkward if you try to add articles:

> ?Mr. Hafner is German and has a buttoned-up manner that is more **a boardroom** than **a barn**.

Now, let's find out if matched count nouns work without any articles outside comparison. Here are a few examples:

> The seven-figure coach is now an easy target for a takeover or a takedown. The Internet is both **boardroom** and **back alley** for angry fans and vindictive rivals to start whisper campaigns, demand firings and disclose N.C.A.A. violations. ([New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2007/06/03/sports/ncaafootball/03roberts.html))

> In the past few years diversity has been a buzzword among brands and many are taking baby steps towards inclusivity, especially outwardly facing in advertising campaigns - but obviously this needs to be magnified across the industry from **boardroom** to **design studio** and every stage in between. ([Glamour](https://www.glamourmagazine.co.uk/gallery/best-black-owned-fashion-brands))

> Chantal accepted Euro-smooches on either cheek of her self-composed face. Pete Smalley radiated that grab-the-bull-by-the-balls zest he no doubt displayed in either **boardroom** or **barroom**. ([Fiction](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=HZh8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT174&dq=%22either%20boardroom%20or%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjts9Dq-o7vAhUKPnAKHQRoAqUQ6AEwAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22either%20boardroom%20or%22&f=false))

Finally, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* talks about "matched nouns" (Pages 409-410):

> vi ***arm** in **arm**, **back** to **back**, **day** after **day**, **mouthful** by **mouthful**, **side** by **side**, **mile** upon **mile*** [repeated nouns]

> vii *from **father** to **son**, from **beginning** to **end**, between **husband** and **wife**, **mother** and **child*** [matched nouns]

> ...

> The examples in [vi–vii] are illustrative of a number of expressions involving repetition of the same noun or contrasting nouns;

> ...

> Similarly, in coordinate structures, bare NPs can optionally be used in repetition: *We searched endlessly for **a spring** or **a cave** to spend the night, but neither **spring** nor **cave** could be found*.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The structure of the example OP gives is 'The result is more Groucho Marx than Karl Marx' where the nouns are pressed into an adjective-like usage, after a link verb such as _be_, rarely seen outside the prenominal position ('a Groucho Marx moustache').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Note that nouns are pressed into an adjective-like usage even outside comparison. See The New York Times example.